# Pagebreak in UIWebview in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone

I am creating Rich Text editor using UIWebView in iOs sdk.I am using java script & HTML code to implement all functionality & using webview as editable content. Now my problem is that I want to insert page break in UIWebView using java-script/Html but page break option is not working in UIWebView.How I can insert page break option in UIWebview?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I use a media query to break a page but it adds two blank pages where i add a blank page. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this after too much search with JS

```
 function makePageBreak(){
                insertHtmlAtCursor('<div id="MyInsertPageBreak" class="pagebreak" ></div>');
            }

 function insertHtmlAtCursor(html) {
                var range, node;
                if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
                    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
                    node = range.createContextualFragment(html);
                    range.insertNode(node);
                } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
                    document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(html);
                }
            }
```

This worked for me. Hope will help you.

Comment: Hi Gagan I am facing the page break problem from an HTML file can you please help me how can i call the above js function and when it should be called?

Comment: If you are working with WebView then call this method as [yourWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScript:@"makePageBreak()"];

Comment: please add some delay in adding Pagebreak after webViewDidFinishLoad. You can use [self performSelector:@selector(YourPageBreakMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];